# openstreet maps: dynamically retrieve shp files in python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, shapefile, mapnik

I manage to install mapnik for python and am able to render maps using a provided `shp` file. Is there a possibility to retrieve dynamically the shape file for the map I want to render (given coordinates) from python? or do I need to download the whole OSM files, and import them into my own database?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic retrieval of data from shapefiles is not suggested for large applications. The best practice is to dump the shapefile in databases like postgres (shp2pgsql) & generated the map using mapnik & tile them using tilecache.